# [brave-kafka-interceptor-0.6.0 and debezium/connect]

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, zipkin, debezium-connect

I run the docker-compose.yml.There is a kafka connect debezium/connect image and I added the jar: brave-kafka-interceptor-0.6.0.jar to the path plugin.
As you can see below the brave-kafka-interceptor-0.6.0.jar plugin was loaded by the jvm.
But when we deploy the kafka-connect debezium connector the connector gives me a class not found error.
Having worked on a similar subject would you have any possible resolutions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The docker compose is:

```html
version: '3.8'
services:
    kafka-1:
        image: debezium/kafka:2.4
        container_name: kafka-1
        ports:
            - 9092:9092
        environment:
            - CLUSTER_ID=ZGRkZDM1YTA1MzQwNGQyYT
            - BROKER_ID=1
            - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka-1:9092,2@kafka-2:9093,3@kafka-3:9094
            - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:39092,CONTROLLER://kafka-1:9092
            - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka-1:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:39092
            - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
            - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    kafka-2:
        image: debezium/kafka:2.4
        container_name: kafka-2
        ports:
            - 9093:9093
        environment:
            - CLUSTER_ID=ZGRkZDM1YTA1MzQwNGQyYT
            - BROKER_ID=2
            - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka-1:9092,2@kafka-2:9093,3@kafka-3:9094
            - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://:29093,EXTERNAL://:39093,CONTROLLER://kafka-2:9093
            - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka-2:29093,EXTERNAL://localhost:39093
            - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
            - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    kafka-3:
        image: debezium/kafka:2.4
        container_name: kafka-3
        ports:
            - 9094:9094
        environment:
            - CLUSTER_ID=ZGRkZDM1YTA1MzQwNGQyYT
            - BROKER_ID=3
            - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka-1:9092,2@kafka-2:9093,3@kafka-3:9094
            - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://:29094,EXTERNAL://:39094,CONTROLLER://kafka-3:9094
            - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka-3:29094,EXTERNAL://localhost:39094
            - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
            - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL

    kconnect:
        image: debezium/connect:2.5
        container_name: kconnect
        ports:
            - 8083:8083
            - 9012:9012
        environment:
            CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
            OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
            STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_statuses
            BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka-1:29092,kafka-2:29093,kafka-3:29094
            KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR: /kafka/connect, /kafka/others_connectors
            CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: brave.kafka.interceptor.TracingProducerInterceptor
            CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: brave.kafka.interceptor.TracingConsumerInterceptor
            CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY: All
            CONNECT_PRODUCER_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: KAFKA
            CONNECT_PRODUCER_ZIPKIN_SENDER_NAME: HTTP
            CONNECT_PRODUCER_ZIPKIN_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka-1:29092,kafka-2:29093,kafka-3:29094
            KAFKA_OPTS: "-verbose:class"
            KAFKA_CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.connector"
            KAFKA_CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "DEBUG"
        depends_on:
            - kafka-1
            - kafka-2
            - kafka-3

        volumes:
            - ./libs/brave-kafka-interceptor-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/kafka/others_connectors/brave-kafka-interceptor-0.6.0.jar
            - ./confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.7.4/lib:/kafka/others_connectors/jdbc

    db:
        container_name: db
        image: postgres:16.1-alpine3.19
        restart: always
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres # Le user pour se connecter à postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres # Le password pour se connecter à postgres
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'
        volumes:
            - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data # Répertoire où seront stocké les données postgres
            - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql # Le script pour préparer la base de données destinée à notre exemple.
        command: [ "postgres", "-c", "wal_level=logical" ] #Le wal_level doit être "logical" pour faire fonctionner le connecteur postgres debezium.

    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4:8.1
        container_name: pgadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8888:80"
        environment:
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: postgres@domain-name.com # The PostgreSQL user (useful to connect to the database)
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: postgres # The PostgreSQL password (useful to connect to the database)

 #openzipkin/zipkin
    zipkin:
        image: openzipkin/zipkin
        container_name: zipkin
        environment:
            STORAGE_TYPE: mem
            KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka-1:29092,kafka-2:29093,kafka-3:29094
        ports:
            - 9411:9411
```

Thks,

Comment: Interceptors are not Connect plugins. Try adding CLASSPATH environment variable with value `/kafka/others_connectors/*.jar`